# Calling Functions With std::optional Parameters

Tags: c++, option-type, std, boost-optional

I have a function whose signature is:

```
void func(std::optional<std::string> os = std::nullopt);
```

(I’m aliasing `std::experimental::optional` until `std::optional` is officially available.)

However, I’m having difficulty calling it cleanly. The compiler will refuse to perform two implicit conversions (`const char*` ➝ `std::string` ➝ `std::optional<std::string>`) to call it with a raw C-string literal. I *can* do this:

```
func(std::string("Hello"));
```

And the compiler will figure that a `std::optional` is needed, and do the conversion. However, this is way too verbose. Thanks to C++11, I can also do this:

```
func({"Hello"});
```

While this is *way better*, it's still not ideal. I'd like to be able to call this function like any other that takes a `std::string`. **Is this possible?** Making the function take another parameter type is okay, as long as it behaves similarly to/is directly convertible to `std::optional`. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with simply overloading the function, with no parameters and a `std::string` parameter?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik As far as I know, that would require three overloads to avoid mass-duplication: `void func(std::optional<std::string> os = std::nullopt)`, `void func(std::string s)` and `void func()`. The latter two would call the former, constructing the optional as appropriate. I’d be happy if you could prove me wrong. While this does technically work, there’s just a lot of unnecessary interface code. Thanks, though.

Comment: Well, is `func("std::string literal"s);` okay?

Comment: Huh… I never knew that existed. That might be the best solution. If you add it as a proper answer, I’ll happily accept it if nothing better comes along.
Reference for others: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy, why would you need a third overload `func()` if there's a default argument for `func(std::optional<std::string> = std::nullopt)`?

Comment: N.B. the error is a defect in `std::experimental::optional`, see [LWG DR 2451](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2451). There's no error with `std::optional`, nor with GCC's `std::experimental::optional`, but not all implementations have the fix for the DR. If you were really using `std::optional` and not faking it with `std::experimental::optional` there would be no error.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's… a good point. Oops. So, I suppose one overload taking a std::string that forwards to the main one wouldn't be that bad. As for the defect report, it's good to know that this'll work better once the libc++ people fix this (see https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C++14 adds a bunch of user-defined literals to the standard library in order to make code less verbose. It looks something like this:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;              // needed
// using namespace std::literals;                  // also ok, but unnecessary 
// using namespace std::literals::string_literals; // also ok, but why??

int main()
{
    std::string str = "string"s;
                       ^^^^^^^^
                       // This is a std::string literal, 
                       // so std::string's copy constructor is called in this case
}
```

Also take a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) for reference.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with a bit of templates and sfinae:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value &&
    !std::is_constructible<std::optional<std::string>, T>::value>* = nullptr>
void func(T&& s) {
    void func(std::string(std::forward<T>(s)));
}
```

This overload will be picked when a string would be constructible with a forwarded `T` but   only when `std::optional<std::string>` is not constructible.

You function will be callable with any object that a string can be constructed with:

```
func("potato"); // working, forward the string literal to a std::string
```

Comment: I’d likely use this approach if I were writing a library that should be easy-to-use for the end-user. The other answer is better for my case, but this is a great alternative. Thanks a bunch.